# How to find the complexity of the given algorithm?

Tags: data-structures

[image]

Consider the above procedure, which finds the location LOC1 of the largest element and the location LOC2 of the second largest element in an array DATA with n>1 elements. Let C(n) denote the number of comparisons during the execution of the procedure.

So, I was unable to find the following points related to it:

1. Find C(n) for the best case.
2. Find C(n) for the worst case.
3. Find C(n) for the average case for n=4, assuming all arrangements of the given elements in DATA are equally likely.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void findd(int arr[],int n,int loc1,int loc2)
{
int first=arr[0],second=arr[1];
if(first<second)
{
    int temp=first;
    first=second;
    second=temp;

    loc2=0,loc1=1;
    }

for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
{
    if(first<arr[i])
    {
        second=first;
        first=arr[i];
        loc2=loc1;
        loc1=i;
        }
        else if(second<arr[i])
        {
            second=arr[i];
            loc2=i;
            }
    }


cout<<"index of max element"<<loc1+1<<"  index of min element "<<loc2+1<<"\n";

}


int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
int arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];
    }


findd(arr,n,0,1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

so accoriding  to the solution and your algorithm your this code will have
for n  elements :

O(n)=  worst complexity....as it will iterate n times if the max no is at the end 
O(n)= best case as if the max no is present at the beginning but still it have to compare it with all the elements in the array

O(n)= average complexity

O(1)=space complexity...

hope you will like the answer ..:)

Comment: I can understand your point but still, in one traverse it takes 3 comparisons. So don't you think it will change the complexity?

Comment: actually the constant are removed during calculating the complexity..like if the complexity is 5n then it will considered as (n)...if the complexity is 5n^2 then it will be written as n^2..we remove the constant..